# what is r.Scheme()+":///test.server" in grpc Dial call in all grpc test cases

Tags: grpc-go

Normally we pass the server address like for example "localhost:56666" or "someserver:9999" to the Dial method of grpc-go.

ex: grpc.Dial("localhost:56666", grpc.WithInSecure())

But in the test cases given in grpc-go repo (refer below links), the first argument to Dial is mentioned as "*Dial(**r.Scheme()+":///test.server"**, WithInsecure(), WithTimeout(5*time.Second))*". When I print that value by running these go test files, I observed this address value as "**bykrwuxel00s:///test.server**"

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/balancer/roundrobin/roundrobin_test.go#L102

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/clientconn_test.go#L135

How does this work as a valid server address?

Answer (score 0):

The "scheme" element of a gRPC URI target basically indicates only the target's "type". See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md#name-syntax for more details.

For example, in that way, gRPC clients can look at that type and decide what name resolution mechanism to use (internally, each "resolver" is registered under a unique scheme).

In this case, it looks like that test is using a custom resolver that it generated from a call to "GenerateAndRegisterManualResolver", which dynamically generated a unique scheme for global registration: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/7c1d326729dc9b0a07135f8902ddcc050ff8ab64/resolver/manual/manual.go#L89